# Parsing and looking up a string with variable number of fields java

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have to read a file and store the values and then later do a lookup.

For e.g., the file will look as follows:

```
Gryffindor = 5
Gryffindor.Name.Harry = 10
Gryffindor.Name.Harry.Cloak.Black = 15
and so on...
```

I need to store these (I was thinking of a map). Later, I need to process every character and lookup this map to assign them points. Suppose I encounter Harry, I know that he's from Gryffindor and he's wearing a blue cloak. I will have to lookup this map (or whatever object I use) as

```
Gryffindor.Name.Harry.Cloak.Blue
```

which should return me nothing. I then need to fall back to just the name and lookup

```
Gryffindor.Name.Harry
```

that should return me a 10.

Similarly, if I lookup for Ron, (suppose he's wearing black),

```
Gryffindor.Name.Ron.Cloak.Black
```

should return nothing, fall back to

```
Gryffindor.Name.Ron
```

again nothing, fall back to

```
Gryffindor
```

which should return 5.

What will be an elegant way to store and read this data? I was thinking of using a map for storing the key value pairs and then a switch case to read them back. How would you do it?

Comment: Someone mentioned `Properties` before, it basically serializes and deserializes a map to/from a human readable file. If this is not an exercise, take a look at how it works.

Comment: What's the problem you are having with using a map? Or have you even tried anything yet?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I was looking for ideas before I started with the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Java has a built-in [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class that implements `Map` and can read and write the data format you describe (see that class's [`load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29) and [`store()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#store%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) methods).

There's nothing in there to implement your "fall back to a higher-level key" feature, so you'll need to write a method that looks in the `Properties` instance for data under the desired key, and keeps trying successively shorter versions of the same key if it finds nothing.